# Changing list value in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have inventory with a very complicated structure. For my specific installation I want to override only some values. For example, I have structure:

```
---    
System:
  atr1: 47
  config:
    - nodes:
        - logger:
            id: 'all'
            svr: 'IEW'
        - Database:
            constr: 'login/pass@db'
  atr2: 'some value'
```

I want to override severity of the logger, i.e. add statistic information 
**svr: 'IEWS'**. I want to provide an override within **--extra-vars** parameter.

In ansible.cfg -> hash_behaviour = merge

I don't want to use something like - **svr: "{{ svr_custom | default('IEW') }}"**, because there are too many parameters, and thus it will be difficult to write the entire inventory in such way.
I read about [combine filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), but I can't use it, when I had to override only one item in hash.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Hi igv! Can you tell us what you have already tried and what problems you encountered? And please take your time to read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The way you found is the simplest one. It's verbose to write but very easy to debug and to fix.
2. If you *REALLY* want to shrink this job, you can write your own lookup plugin. (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup.html).

From my experience, I really want to say that direct and dumb approach (write verbose) is much better for overall maintainability. A next person will see a dumb dump (pun intended) which is easy to fix, not a some obscure python snippet.

To make life easier you may want to store this configuration as a separate file (with all jinja pieces) and use lookup (st right from docs):

```
# Since 2.4, you can pass in variables during evaluation
 - debug: msg="{{ lookup('template', './some_template.j2', template_vars=dict(x=42)) }} is evaluated with x=42"
```

Moreover, you can use Jinja's `|from_yaml` (or `from_json`) to convert loaded and processed template into data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I read about combine filter, but I can't use it, when I had to override only one item in hash.

Why is that? Wouldn't *new_svr* defined in *--extra-vars* achieve what you want?

```
- set_fact:                                                                                                   
    System: "{{ System | combine({'config':[{'nodes':[{'logger':{'svr':new_svr }}]}]}, recursive=True) }}"
```